# Time indiscrete or Temporally indiscrete

Tags: meaning, word-choice, compound-adjectives

Is the word combination `temporally indiscrete` or `time indiscrete` correct adjectives, when describing for instance a system which works on the basis of continuous time (and not discrete time)? I am searching about a name for a piece of software i am working on, and the name i came up with is

> Temporally Indiscrete Music Engraving System

which also will have the nice short form `TIMES`. So there is no full sentence as context, but it's just a part of a name.

Comment: Can you provide some context? An example sentence always helps. In general, I'd say "non-discrete" instead of "indiscrete", which I've never seen used.

Comment: ... Yes, at least one example sentence is needed. 'Indiscrete' is a valid variant of 'non-discrete', though neither 'a temporally indiscrete system' nor 'a temporally non-discrete system' sounds too appetising (though neither looks ill-formed). 'A continuous-time system' is perhaps better.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am writing a music notation software, and wanted to use this adjective as part of it's name which should be: ` Temporally Indiscrete Music Engraving System`.

Comment: I suspect that many people are going to inadvertently read that as "*Temporarily Indiscreet*".

Answer (score -1):

I think 'indiscrete' is the wrong word in this case: it means you cannot keep a secret, rather than being the opposite of discrete (Which is what I think you are trying to say), when used in the Signal processing or IT field:

"*Discrete time signals are “the signals or quantities that can be **defined and represented at certain time instants of the sequence.**” These are finite or countable sets of number sequences.*"

You could try **"Time independent"**, which I think will describe your software more clearly and maintain your 'TIME' acronym.

Comment: The word ***indiscrete*** would indeed be the opposite of discrete. The word you're thinking of is ***indiscreet***, which is the very error @raybutterworth predicted (-: Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Based on this page (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indiscrete) i thought indiscrete could not be confused with indiscreet. Also there are two different entries on the LEO online dictionary for __indiscrete__ (https://dict.leo.org/german-english/indiscrete) and __indiscreet__ (https://dict.leo.org/german-english/indiscreet).

Comment: Quite right Jim: my mistake: indiscreet = imprudent, indiscrete = not separated into distinct parts / blurred...